# NSString losing new lines when added to mail body

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nsstring, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am storing some text as an `NSString`. The text contains multiple paragraphs. When I log or display the text the new line characters are inserted correctly.

However, when I use the `MFMailComposeViewController` and add the text to the mail's body, the new lines are removed and the text runs together.

What is causing this, and how do I preserve the formatting?

Comment: You can preserve formatting by making the view controller treat the text as HTML.

Comment: Thanks - I am already doing this.

Comment: Sure it's valid HTML? Maybe the controller is splitting hair :P

Comment: It was the \n replacement I needed - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(OK, if everyone writes an answer from my comment, then I write one too...)

If you instruct the view controller to treat the text as HTML, you can preserve its formatting, else it'll be discarded. Note that in this case you'll have to feed it actual HTML, of course (`\n` in HTML isn't any good). So try:

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSString *html = [[body componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set]
    componentsJoinedByString:@"<br />"];
[viewController setMessageBody:html isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: I'll throw you the +1 considering your answer is better than mine, but I did start on my answer before you posted the comment. It turns out it's painfully slow the write an answer with code from my iPad :)

Comment: @0x7fffffff Let you get that back :P I know that feeling, bro.

Comment: It's funny, I've seen posts here and there from people anxious for Xcode for iPad, but can you imagine how terrible that would actually be....

Comment: @0x7fffffff I'm working on an IDE for iPad. I often write code on my iPad, in fact. But I miss syntax highlighting and automatic makefile generation very much.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the way you're doing this should be working, if by line break you're referring to `\n`. One alternative would be to replace the occurrences of `\n` with `<br>` and set the composer's isHTML flag to YES:

```
NSString *emailString = [myParagraphs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:emailString isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by H2CO3 in comments, you need to wrap it as HTML content.

```
NSString *myEmailBody = @"First Line <br/> Second <br/> Third";
[composer setMessageBody:myEmailBody isHTML:YES];
```